# Why do the property and the value disappear from the real database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I try to console.log the user as below showing for the further manipulation of it but the weird thing is the places properties somehow disappeared, and if you check on the database, it's still there.

Anyone, please tell me what's wrong ...

```
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');
const getCoordsForAddress = require('../util/location');
const PlaceSchema = require('../models/place_schema');
const UserSchema = require('../models/user_schema');
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const { findById } = require('../models/place_schema');


const getPlaceById = async (req, res, next) => {
  const placeId = req.params.pid;
  let place;
  try {
    place = await PlaceSchema.findById(placeId);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Somthing wehnt wrong, could not find a place', 500);
    return next(error);
  };

  if (!place) {
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find a place for the provided id.', 404);
    return next(error);
  } else {
    res.json({ place: place.toObject({ getters: true }) });
  };
};

const getPlacesByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.params.uid;
  let places;
  try {
    places = await PlaceSchema.find({ creator: userId });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Something went wrong, couldn nott find the place', 500);
    return next(error);
  };

  if (!places || places.length === 0) {
    return next(
      new HttpError('Could not find a place for the provided user id.', 404)
    );
  };
  res.json({ places: places.map(p => p.toObject({ getters: true })) });
};

const createPlace = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors);
    return next(new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data', 422));
  };

  const { title, description, address, creator, image } = req.body;

  let coordinates;
  try {
    coordinates = await getCoordsForAddress(address);
  } catch (error) {
    return next(error);
  }

  const createdPlace = new PlaceSchema({
    title,
    description,
    image,
    location: coordinates,
    address,
    creator
  });

  // check if a exist userid is existing
  let user;
  try {
    user = await UserSchema.findById(creator);
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Creating place failed, please try again.', 500)
    return next(error);
  };

  if (!user) {
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find user for provided id', 404)
    return next(error);
  }

  try {
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await createdPlace.save({ session: sess });
    user.places.push(createdPlace);
    await user.save({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Creating place failed, please try again.', 500);
    return next(error);
  };

  res.status(201).json({ place: createdPlace });
};

const updatePlace = async (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors);
    return next(HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data', 422));
  };

  const { title, description } = req.body;
  const placeId = req.params.pid;

  try {
    PlaceSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(placeId, {
      title, description
    })
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Somthing went wrong, could not update the place.', 500)
    return next(error);
  };
 
  res.status(200).json({ place: updatedPlace.toObject({ getters: true }) });
};

const deletePlace = async (req, res, next) => {
  const placeId = req.params.pid;
  let thePlace;
  let creator;
  try {
    thePlace = await PlaceSchema.findById(placeId);
    creator =  await UserSchema.findById(thePlace.creator);
    
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError('Somthing went wrong, could delete the place', 500);
    return next(error);
  };
 console.log(creator);
  try {
    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await PlaceSchema.findByIdAndDelete(placeId, { session: sess });
    await creator.places.pull(creator);
    await UserSchema.save({ session: sess });
    await sess.commitTransaction();
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log(err)
    const error = new HttpError('Somthing went wrong, could delete the place', 500);
    return next(error);
  };

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted place.' });
};

exports.getPlaceById = getPlaceById;
exports.getPlacesByUserId = getPlacesByUserId;
exports.createPlace = createPlace;
exports.updatePlace = updatePlace;
exports.deletePlace = deletePlace;
```

[When console.log the user, there is no places of an array showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCLcL.png)

[But it's actually in the database, somehow it disappears when console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjaWq.jpg)